# ML-Kit Translation Updating translation models

Tags: android, google-translate, google-mlkit

Do offline translation models support the update? If so, how can I check if the model has an update?

Answer (score 0):

The offline translation models do not upgrade automatically. ML Kit can upgrade them with future releases. When that happens, such model upgrades will be documented in ML Kit's [release notes](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/release-notes).